# How to show alphabet words spell for list in php

Tags: php

How to show words spell for list in php. Example

```
 $word=bat;
if a=angry
   b=beautiful
   t=thin
echo $word;

result
b=beautiful
a=angry
t=thin
```

Comment: Set up an array with the letters as keys, and the values as words (e.g. `$alphabet = ['a'=>'angry', 'b'=>'beautiful', ...]`) as start; then split $word into an array of individual characters (`$letters = str_split($word)`) and iterate over that displaying the appropriate alphabet value for each character (`foreach $letters as $letter) { echo $alphabet[$letter]; }`)

Comment: ok.use str_split() php function? sorry my english

Comment: [str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) PHP has very good, detailed documentation in a wide range of languages; learn to use it

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker.How to show First letter uppercase

Comment: [ucfirst()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) PHP has very good, detailed documentation in a wide range of languages; learn to use it

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you should have array with words, and use your word as `Char` array. So in the end, I would propose, something like this:

```
function spell_word($word){
   $spell_words = array("a"=>"angry", "b"=>"beautiful", "t"=>"thin" );
   $result = array();
   for( $index=0; $i < strlen( $word ); $i++ ){
     $result[] = array( "letter"=> $word[i], "word" => $spell_words[$word[i]]);
   }
   return $result;
}

var_dump(spell_word("bat"));
```